# Selecting a item from a list of filenames in Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes-app

My app needs to select a given filename from a list of filenames presented by iTunes' "Import Playlist" dialog. According to Accessibility Inspector the majority of the list's parent have no description and one item is described as an "NSBox".
*MY SPECIFIC PROBLEM IS THAT TRYING TO REFER TO THE "[NSBox]" AS "group 1" FAILS WITH THE RUNTIME ERROR ESSENTIALLY SAYING THE NUMBER IS TOO LARGE?!*

This is a near identical situation to my earlier question [How do I refer to an object in a window whose Accessibility Inspector description is "<empty description> (group) [NSBox]" in Applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054693/how-do-i-refer-to-an-object-in-a-window-whose-accessibility-inspector-descriptio) for which the **only** answer presented an alternate method of accomplishing my specific task at the time.

The list item marked with a * rather than a - is the actual item I had selected in Accessibility Inspector. The full hierarchy of the specific item I need to select in one example case is:

```
- iTunes (application) [ITNSApplication]
- import (dialog) [NSOpenPanel]
- <empty description> (group) [NSBox]
- <empty description> (split group) [Fl_TSplitView]
- <empty description> (split group) [Fl_TSplitView]
- <empty description> (scroll area) [Fl_TListScrollView]
- (list view) [Fl_TListView]
- <empty description> (outline row) [NSOutlineRow]
* Library.xml (cell) [NSTableViewCellMockElement]
    - Library.xml (text field) [Fl_TListNameFieldCell]
    - <empty description> (image) [NSImageCell)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSBox]'s are called "outline"s by Applescript so the specific solution would be `tell app "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to select row [number or variable here] of list view 1 of scroll area 1 of split group 1 of split group 1 of group 1 of window "import" [or "its front window"` and yes, that is the correct spelling of "its"].