# Use AppleScript to list the names of all UI elements in a window (GUI scripting)

Tags: user-interface, applescript, ui-automation

One line summary - I'm looking for a way to get AppleScript itself to reveal the name it expects a specific piece of window content (UI element) to be referred to as in a "tell" statement.

How do I get AppleScript to list the name it wants me to use to refer to a window's contents?

for example I can say `tell current application to tell its front window's list 1 to ...`

I'm trying to find out the term like "list 1" for all of the window's contents so I can cross-reference it with the list from Accessibility Inspector..

I tried this code but the first line generates an error saying "error "Can’t make names of «class ects» of window 1 of «class prcs» \"iTunes\" of application \"System Events\" into type string." number -1700 from names of «class ects» of window 1 of «class prcs» "iTunes" to string"

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to set elementNames to the names of the entire contents of its front window as string
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document at the front
    set the text of the front document to elementNames
    set WrapToWindow to text 2 thru -1 of (localized string "&Wrap to Window")
end tell
```

Comment: Perhaps relevant, check out: https://github.com/alldritt/UIBrowser4/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In GUI scripting, using **`entire contents [of]`** on a process's window in the context of the `System Events` application returns a **list of all the UI elements (GUI controls)** of the frontmost window in the active application (the ***entire hierarchy* flattened to a list**):

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
  tell front window of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
    set uiElems to entire contents
  end tell
end tell
```

<sup>If you run the above in `Script Editor`, the Result pane will show a list of *object specifiers* - e.g., `button 1 of window "Main" of application process "Music" of application "System Events"` - which do not directly reveal specific information, but from which you can glean least the *type* (class) of UI element (`button`, in this example) and the *position* among its siblings of the same type (`1`)</sup>

To target Music, for instance, substitute `application process "Music"` for `(first application process whose frontmost is true)` .

Note that **if you only want the *immediate child elements*, you can use `UI elements [of]` instead of `entire contents [of]`**, and you can apply it not just to a window (to get the top-level UI elements), but to any of the UI elements it contains to get *their* children.

---

You cannot extract properties of these elements by converting the enumeration to a *string* with `as string` as you've tried, but you can extract properties in a `repeat` loop:

Assuming that by *names* you mean the *class* names (such as `table` and `button`), try this:

```applescript
set classNames to {}
tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
        repeat with uiElem in entire contents as list
            set classNames to classNames & (class of uiElem as string)
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that **`as list` is inexplicably needed (as of macOS 10.12.3) to make this work** (not necessary with `UI elements [of]`).

This will return a list of class names such as `{"splitter group", "text field", "button", "scroll area", ... }`, which in itself is not enough to target a specific element, however, because the hierarchy has been flattened.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Accessibility Inspector.app that comes with Xcode