# Is there a way to monitor and control macOS applications from another custom built application or script?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is a general question where I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction. I'm looking to be able to monitor the Mac application Logic Pro X. It's for a university research project that focuses on DAW control, I need to be able to monitor specific information from the DAW - primarily the displayed text infromation of Tracks and/or other aspects.

The control aspect is not such a major factor as this can be achieved using MIDI and/or keyboard shortcuts. But wondering if anyone knows of a way of monitoring some of the GUI text information from one application in another application.

Done some research online and can't seem to find much on the topic.

I've not done much in C based programming but know Python and Javascript quite well so this is going to be my next project to try to learn Objective-C.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - I have just found this, [Use AppleScript to list the names of all UI elements in a window (GUI scripting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231133/use-applescript-to-list-the-names-of-all-ui-elements-in-a-window-gui-scripting)

would this approach using AppleScript work here?

EDIT - [Areas of the GUI needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li1Fo.png)

Here's a screenshot of the text I need to access
I have actually been able to get to all of these using atomacos in Python, the text is contained in the AXDescription of the correct buttons. However these aren't always at the same place in the hiearchy so I'm having to ignore errors and find the correct path. I'm also getting the text constantly in a while loop, it would be better if I could observe the properties to see if they change. Here is the Python code I'm using to get just the track names, I've also managed to get down inside the tracks to get the audio effect names.

```
import atomacos

logic = atomacos.getAppRefByBundleId('com.apple.logic10')
for w in logic.windows():
    title = w.AXTitle
    try:
        if title.split(' - ')[1] == 'Tracks':
            window = w
    except IndexError:
        continue
for section in window.AXChildren:
    if section.AXRoleDescription == 'group':
        try:
            if section.AXChildren[1].AXDescription == 'Tracks':
                tracks = section.AXChildren[1].AXChildren[0].AXChildren[1].AXChildren[0].AXChildren[0]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue

while True:
    track_list = {}
    for track in tracks.AXChildren:
        try:
            for item in track.AXChildren:
                try:
                    if item.AXRoleDescription == 'text field':
                        track_list[item.AXDescription] = item
                except AttributeError:
                    continue
                except atomacos.errors.AXErrorIllegalArgument:
                    continue
            track_list.keys()

        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Comment: AppleScript is the normal tool for controlling other applications on MacOS. Logic Pro X is not directly scriptable, but there's still a lot that can be done with GUI scripting. I can't tell you whether it will suffice without knowing the specifics of what you're trying to do, though. I can get a copy of LPX to use for script-testing purposes, but I don't know what the app does or how to work it. If you give me a (simplified) example of something you might want to do, I'll see if I can write an example script to make it happen.

Comment: I have just experimented with AppleScript and found that like you say Logic Pro X doesn't have a scripting library.

So basically I want to be able to get the list of Tracks - which would be something like [Drums, Bass, Guitar, Vocals] etc and then navigate that list by index number. So to select Bass you'd do something like tracks[1].

I have just started looking at the Accessibility API and the Python wrapper for it 'atomacos', although this is just for testing purposes because it requires x-code, I'm assuming there's something that could be done with the API in Obj-C?

Comment: GUI-scripting always works through the Accessibility API. I've only done it through AppleScript and python; I've never done it from objC, but yes, it can be done. Which language you want to use depends details I don't know (e.g., python gives better access to keystroke events than AppleScript; AppleScript is easier to use than either of the others; objC is most powerful, but is going to get you tangled up with sandboxes and security issues...)

Comment: OK, at the moment I've gotten Python atomacos working, and it's finding the Logic window, title etc. Just can't find any of the contents. I guess I just keep looking at AXChildren, or is there a faster way? I'm pretty good with Python but slightly out of my depth with any of the Apple API's.

Comment: So I've managed to find name of the currently focused track in the main window, and also the list of tracks in another window. But that window is not always open. May have to keep trying.

Comment: OK problem solved (ish). Managed to get down to the track names I need, in all windows. Interested to hear how/if this would be possible using Apple script, or potentially Obj-C as the Python solution I've got right now is only really suitable for testing and proof of concept.

Comment: This evening I'll take a look at it with AppleScript  just so you have a demo. GUI scripting is always a bit of hunt and peck, though if you know how to use System Events or use the Accessibility Inspector in Xcode (Xcode menu  → Open Developer Toll → Accessibility Inspector), it can make probing the hierarchy easier.

Comment: Awesome thank you. At the moment I have a working solution for testing, but it's not great. I'm having to constantly catch errors and check the entire hierachy and the labels at each level to find the right objects because depending on the GUI the positions can change, so the paths are almost never the same. There must be a better way. Im starting to wonder if its possible to find the list of tracks at the start and the create some kind of observer and callback on it.

Comment: I looked at Logic Pro X last night: annoying interface... It would be nice if you put up a screenshot with the data you want captured circled, so that I know I'm getting to the right thing. Also, if you could tell me what parts of the GUI change, it would help; there are tricks for compensating for that, but I'm having a hard time seeing what you need.

Comment: I've edited the post. The areas that 'can' sometimes change depending on the user are the Library and Inspector. As well as other areas. Pressing Y or I on the keyboard will open and close them. This changes the index of the other sections in the list of Children. At the moment I'm finding them by checking all of the descriptions for ones that match 'Tracks' and 'Mixer'.

Comment: Adding in an example AppleScript as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example GUI script that shows you how to reliably find the two areas you marked, and gather information you want. I've shown how to find both the 'tracks' area and the 'Mixer area', but I only drilled down into the 'Tracks' area you give you examples of things work. If you have trouble piecing together the other area, let me know and I'll add more.

```
tell application "Logic Pro X" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Logic Pro X"
        tell window "Untitled - Tracks"
            (*
                the following lines find the main 'tracks' group and the 'mixer' group, by looking for
                 stable features of their respective toolbars. the first looks for the 
                 'Horizontal Zoom' slider, the second for the 'Wide Channel Strips' radio button. 
                 the doubled 'whose' queries look confusing, but basically they say "Find the group 
                 whose first group is a toolbar, whose last (slider's/radiobutton's) description is...  
                 Once we have those, we can reliably find these area, regardless of whether other groups 
                 are opened or closed"
            *)
            set main_track_group to first group whose its (first group whose role description is "Toolbar")'s last slider's description is "Horizontal Zoom"
            try
                set mixer_group to first group whose its (first group whose role description is "Toolbar")'s last radio group's last radio button's description is "Wide Channel Strips"
            on error
                -- mixer group is not open, so open it
                keystroke "x"
                delay 2
                set mixer_group to first group whose its (first group whose role description is "Toolbar")'s first radio group's last radio button's description is "Wide Channel Strips"
            end try

            tell main_track_group
                set track_group to first group whose role description is not "Toolbar"
                tell track_group
                    tell first splitter group's second splitter group's first scroll area's first group
                        (*
                            And here we're at the list of tracks. Tracks can be addressed by index, like so:
                        *)
                        set track_item to third group
                        (* 
                            or you can find them by name, with a little trickery. The double 'whose' 
                            command is a little hard to parse, but it means "Find the first group that has a 
                            text field element with the descrition 'Bass'"
                        *)
                        set track_item to first group whose its (first UI element whose role description is "text field")'s description is "Audio Track"
                        tell track_item
                            (* 
                                once you have the track, you can access and set any values you could 
                                normally see or set in the interface, by finding the relevent UI element. 
                                all of these ui elements have their names in the 'description'
                                field. examples:
                            *)
                            -- log a list of all the visible UI elements
                            log (get description of every UI element)
                            -- get mute checkbox
                            set mute_check to first UI element whose role description is "checkbox" and description is "Mute"
                            -- log current state of the checkbox
                            log (get value of mute_check)
                            -- click the checkbox to toggle its state
                            click mute_check
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

If you want to constantly sample these over time, then your best bet is to create a stay-open application with an idle handler.  The template for that is this:

```
global main_track_group, mixer_group -- global variables are available everywhere in the script

on run
    (*
        use this area to initialize stuff. In particular, initialize the two group variables 
        here so that you only have to do it once; whose commads are slow and expensive
    *)
end run

on idle
    (*
        use GUI scripting to extract the values here. the return value (below) is the idle time, in seconds: e.g. 'return 1' means that this hnalder will be called once a second. make it as small as you need to get the info you want, but not so small that this app is eating up processing time'
    *)
    return 1
end idle

on quit
    (*
do whatever cleanup you need to do here
*)
    continue quit
end quit
```

Save it as an application, with the `Stay open after run handler` checkbox checked.

Comment: Thank you so much for demonstrating this for me, it seems to follow on the same lines as the Python, and the solution of waiting was how I've ended up handling the while loop. But I feel like this would be better, would it be possible to run this as a background process and communicate with it somehow? It's great that you can get or set some of the values, the next thing I'm trying to figure out is how to set the focus. So which track is highlighted in either window (it would be the same). I've never done anything with AppleScript before so this is new territory for me.

Comment: On my machine when I run this I keep getting the error error "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 3 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of group 3 of window \"Untitled - Tracks\" of application process \"Logic Pro X\". Invalid index." number -1719 from group 3 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of group 3 of window "Untitled - Tracks" of application process "Logic Pro X"

Comment: Use the application template I gave to create a process that you can communicate with. As far as the error goes: can you tell me where in the script execution it occurs?

Comment: OK. 

The error occurs on this line:

set track_item to third group

It does it even if I change the index.

The only other thing I can see being a problem is the window title. This will change depending on what the file is called. In Python I'm handling it by splitting the title on ' - ' and checking the second index, 'Tracks' as this remains constant for this window

Comment: I've just had a look and found you can do something similar in AppleScript in regards to splitting the title.

Comment: Still having trouble with this. It's really odd because I can see the group in the hiearchy but it wont let me access it or do anything with it in AppleScript. Wondering if Python might be the better way to go. I have access to the values, but I can't set any of them. Particularly trying to set the SelectedChildren attribute.

Comment: You can only set things in GUI scripting that you can set directly through the interface. If you want to select the child of an element, you have to navigate down to the child and select it directly. AppleScript or python is largely irrelevant, since the limitation comes from the accessibility framework itself, so use whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: OK Thanks, I'm more comfortable in Python so going to keep going with it. The Apple Script just keeps telling me invalid index.